# Problem using finite difference to solve a initial value problem

Tags: finite-differences, na.numerical-analysis, differential-equations

I tried to use 'finite difference' method to solve an Initial Value Problem (IVP). For the two boundaries I used periodical condition and for the differential operators I used 4th degree center approximations. But as result, I got this thing. Where comes this strange oscillation What do you think could be the problem. Should I use a smaller x step size? Will use a forward approximation help? Thanks.
Actually I am using Matlab's odes15s.

The strange thing is that, if I use a bigger x stepsize, say 0.1, I will get a smooth  result. With s step size 0.06, I will get the result showed in the picture.
I tried ode45, which is based on an explicit Runge-Kutta (4,5) formula, the Dormand-Prince pair and ode23tb, which is an implementation of TR-BDF2. I got the same result.

[image]

\begin{aligned}
\dot{q} & = -\frac{\partial (6*q^2/5*h)}{\partial x}-\frac{3*q}{h^2}+h*h'''-(1+10*cos(pi*t))*h*h'\\
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\dot{h} & = -\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
h(t,0) = h(t,10),q(t,0) = q(t,10)
\end{aligned}

$h(0,x)$, $q(0,x)$ are known.

Comment: This question could do with some improving. At present I don't know it fits in with MO's guidelines (but I'm happy to be corrected).

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about the theoretical reason why you get this result, or are you asking for help to use Matlab? The former question is on-topic, the latter is not, and a specialised Matlab forum might be better placed to help you.

Comment: I am asking about the theoretical reason. The ODE have up to third degree differential operators in it and it is nonlinear.

Comment: MO isn't a place to diagnose software problems but you could make this into a suitable question but you'll have to supply more details.  Could you tell us (1) exactly which differential equation are you studying and what are your boundary conditions? (2) Do you know precisely which method your software is using? `finite difference method' is very vague, to me at least. 

Comment: @Ryan, I edit my question. I hope that will turn it to a suitable question here. thanks

Comment: I edited the title to remove a typo

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that your system actually has smooth solutions?

Comment: What are you plotting here? What is the origin of this equation?

Comment: It is a model of faraday instability in thin fluid film

Comment: what I am plotting here is the height of the fluid surface. It is h in the equation.


Comment: h against x or t? If the instability is caused by your numerical method or a bug, then from my limited experience I would expect the vertical scale to be completely crazy (like 10^10 or something). So this might be really what is going on. You said that it is model of an instability. This kind of behaviour is to be expected?

Comment: Can you please call my name (say @timur) if you answer, so I will get notified.

Comment: In a deleted answer, user "clef" recommends http://scicomp.stackexchange.com 